# How can you make file paths 'OS agnostic' in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, filesystems, filenames

I'm working on some code right now that is screwing up in our integration testing because we run a test job on a EC2 instance of a Windows machine. After fixing the filenames-are-too-long issue, a lot of the paths still aren't resolved properly because many of them are hard-coded for UNIX.

I was looking into nodejs' Path module but I'm not sure what all needs to be changed to make the path names work on both operating systems (other than the backslashes of course). Do I need to prefix these path names for Windows?

Here's some of the code this is failing on:

```
function getDirectories(srcpath) {
//srcPath looks like graph-validator/tests/data/graph-examples/
  return fs.readdirSync(srcpath).filter(function(file) {
    return (
      file !== '.git' && fs.statSync(path.join(srcpath, file)).isDirectory()
    )
  })
}

const dataDirectory = 'graph-validator/tests/data/'

// Generate valid input for included minimal tests
function createDatasetFileList(path) {

  const testDatasetPath = `${dataDirectory}${path}`
 //path is often 'graph-examples/ds001/' 
  if (!isNode) {

    return createFileList(testDatasetPath)
  } else {
    return testDatasetPath
    // testDatasetPath = graph-validator/tests/data/graph-examples/ds001/

  }
}
```

I tried `path.join()` and this seems to partially solve this, at least the slashes.  How can I make these path names fully agnostic across OS'?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `path.sep` ?  https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep